# CSS - How to make IE7 respect min-width

Tags: html, css

IE7 is ignoring my min-width setting.  I read that IE7 supports min-width as long as you are in Standards mode (not quirks).  I specified

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

as my header.  The markup is [valid.](http://validator.w3.org/check)  I still can't get IE7 to respect `min-width`.  What should I do?

---

```
Sample Code

     <table class="ProcedureTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>column data</th>
                <th>column data</th>        
                <th>column data</th>
                <th>column data</th>
                <th>column data</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
                    <tr class="PadColumns">
                        <td class="ExpandName">
                            column data
                        </td>
```

CSS

```
.ExpandName
{
    min-width:25em;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ah Yes.. I ran into this a while ago

check out this link

http://blog.throbs.net/2006/11/17/IE7+And+MinWidth+.aspx

Essentially ... you need to include this shim in JS to manually hack the rule

*Below is the way that I handle it tho*

**Just call the function onload of the body**

```
    /*
author: Rob Eberhardt
desc: fix MinWidth for IE6 & IE7
params: none
returns: nothing
notes: cannot yet fix childless elements like INPUT or SELECT
history:
   2006-11-20 revised for standards-mode compatibility
   2006-11-17 first version
*/
function fixMinWidthForIE(){
   try{
      if(!document.body.currentStyle){return} //IE only
   }catch(e){return}
   var elems=document.getElementsByTagName("*");
   for(e=0; e<elems.length; e++){
      var eCurStyle = elems[e].currentStyle;
      var l_minWidth = (eCurStyle.minWidth) ? eCurStyle.minWidth : eCurStyle.getAttribute("min-width"); //IE7 : IE6
      if(l_minWidth && l_minWidth != 'auto'){
         var shim = document.createElement("DIV");
         shim.style.cssText = 'margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important; border:0 !important; line-height:0 !important; height:0 !important; BACKGROUND:RED;';
         shim.style.width = l_minWidth;
         shim.appendChild(document.createElement("&nbsp;"));
         if(elems[e].canHaveChildren){
            elems[e].appendChild(shim);
         }else{
            //??
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**there is another way to do it as well**

http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/01/16/maximum-and-minimum-height-and-width-in-internet-explorer/

```
    * html div#division { 
   height: expression( this.scrollHeight < 334 ? "333px" : "auto" ); /* sets min-height for IE */
}
```

Comment: +1 The first method works.  The second one I cannot figure out how to translate that to my needs, didn't work.  I don't understand the syntax.  I am curious as to why so many people say IE7 supports min-width in standards mode if in fact, it does not and requires these "hacks".

Comment: yeah it is odd.. the second method works by using  IE specific markup that actually runs JS in the css... kinda cool when you think about it

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey To clarify, it actually does. You're just experiencing a bug that IE7 doesn't respect `min-width` on `<td>`. The second method doesn't work because `* html` selector only targets IE6.

Comment: The first function fixed my `min-width` css in IE7.  Saved me some time, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm a newb so apparently I can't comment on @samccone's first answer above.  Just wanted to add it does work but will generate errors in IE9 the way he is creating the non breaking space element, i.e...

```
shim.appendChild(document.createElement("&nbsp;"));
```

That line can be replaced with...

```
shim.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
```

and all is well.  Hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score 0):

> The markup is valid.

No, `<!DOCTYPE html>` is not valid as far as that era is concerned. As far as I know that became valid only with HTML5, which IE7 is certainly not aware of (IE9 is somewhat aware, not sure about 8). On the page I am working on, `min-width` works just fine even on the `body` tag. However, we're using XHTML on this particular page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Furthermore, other things may take IE out of standards-mode and bring it into quirks mode, so even the right doctype might not fix it for you.
So, if you must use HTML5 and be compatible with IE7 you will have to resort to a `behaviour` CSS attribute, a conditional comment, and/or an IE7-specific script.